# Get number from mysql into php varible

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, get

I have one number in a mysql database
This is my code:

```
$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql1 = "SELECT date FROM test";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$res1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
echo $res1['date'];
```

I want to load that number into variable and count with that variable. After that i will store in same the db and table on the same place

Comment: Exactly how is this code not working?

Comment: Are you trying to make us do your work without actually trying anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$numvar = $res1['date'];
```

There yah go.